# ImageView doesn't show with enough padding?

Tags: android, listview, view, imageview, padding

I currently have an ImageView in a list row layout that displays correctly when the image's source is taller than it is wide, but for some reason when it is wider than it is tall, the image shows too wide. Here is an example, where the top image is too wide (as I've pointed out in blue text in the image), and the one below is as it should be:

[image]

The top image only does this because the bitmap that the ImageView shows is wider than it is tall, for any bitmap that is taller than it is wide it shows correctly like the bottom one. This is the XML for the list row item:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    style="@style/block"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/document_list_height"
        android:layout_marginLeft="6dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
        android:background="@color/lightgray"
        >

        <!-- shadow -->
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:src="@drawable/shadow2"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/documentImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:background="@color/alphared"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            >

            <!-- put in LinearLayout to use weights to define textview width as 75% of match_parent -->
            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:weightSum="4"
                android:gravity="right">

                <appuccino.simplyscan.Extra.CustomTextView
                    android:id="@+id/documentName"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="right"
                    android:textColor="@color/white"
                    app:typeface="light"
                    android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                    android:paddingTop="8dp"
                    android:paddingBottom="4dp"
                    android:singleLine="true"
                    android:text="New Document"
                    android:textSize="27sp"/>

            </LinearLayout>

            <appuccino.simplyscan.Extra.CustomTextView
                android:id="@+id/documentPageCount"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                app:typeface="italic"
                android:layout_marginRight="18dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                android:text="1 page"
                android:textSize="20sp"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.melnykov.fab.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/listItemFAB"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="24dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/list_item_fab_bottom_margin"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_action_share"
            app:fab_colorNormal="@color/fab_red"
            app:fab_colorPressed="@color/darkred"
            app:fab_colorRipple="@color/white"
            app:fab_type="normal"
            android:visibility="visible"/>

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

How can I keep the padding the same on both sides for every item?

Comment: Off topic: There should only be one Floating action button per activity according to Material design specs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:cropToPadding="true"` to your ImageView and then it will respect your padding.

```
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/documentImageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="6dp"
            android:paddingRight="4dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
            android:cropToPadding="true"
            />
```